# How to authenticate from Web API controller endpoint when implementing Identity 2.1 + OWIN OAuth JWT bearer token

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth, owin, jwt

I'm unable to authenticate from within my controller method, as part of my confirm-user-signup workflow and I'm looking for some guidance that my implementation is correct.

My controller method has the following code; I've confirmed that the user is populated (as part of the `FindById` call) but after`SignIn`; `this.Authentication.User.Identity` is not set (`Name` is blank and `IsAuthenticated` is false):

```
this.Authentication.SignOut("JWT");

ApplicationUser user = await this.AppUserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(this.AppUserManager, "JWT");

this.Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = true }, oAuthIdentity);
```

Is this correct way to automate signin when using OWIN OAuth?

The full controller method can be see here:
https://gist.github.com/chrismoutray/8a8e5f6a7b433571613b

For reference, I've been following a set of articles from a blog called *Bit of Tech* which has allowed me to set OWIN OAuth using JWT bearer token.

Part 3 in particular talks about JWT (of 5) : http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/

From the articles I've created custom OAuth provider that inherits from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` and implements the `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`, and when my client code (AngularJS) tries to authenticate using the endpoint `/oauth/token`, I can see that it gives the correct response and the secured endpoints (using Authorise attribute) can then be accessed.

So authentication via the middleware does work but what is the correct way to authenticate from inside a controller method?

Comment: Chris, it is not clear to me why you are implementing a OAuthProvider. Are you issuing tokens or consuming?

Comment: @BrentSchmaltz - I thought about my approach and came at the problem from a different perspective. So now, instead of attempting to signin from inside the controller method using Authentication.SignIn(..). I create a temporary one time password (token) which will be used by the client app to authenticate the user for the first time.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth I thought I’d share the solution I’ve come up with.

> The short answer; I create a temporary one time password (token) which will be used to authenticate users for the first time

Gist here for reference: 
https://gist.github.com/chrismoutray/159e6fd74f45d88efd12

To Summaries – In the `AccountController ConfirmSignUp` method; I use the user-manager to generate a custom token which I’ve called `GRANT-ACCESS`, then redirect to my `confirm-signup` page with the username and token in the uri.
My angular app resolves the ui-route to `confirm-signup` and performs a login, passing the token as the password.

```
var tokenResult = this.AppUserManager.GenerateUserTokenAsync("GRANT-ACCESS", userId);
string token = tokenResult.Result;

Uri redirectLocation = new Uri(
    string.Format("http://localhost:45258/#/confirm-signup?user={0}&token={1}", 
    Uri.EscapeDataString(user.UserName), Uri.EscapeDataString(token)));

return Redirect(redirectLocation);
```

Finally there is an amendment to `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials`, so that if the `FindAsync` (by username and password) doesn’t return the user then I try again but this time treating the `context.Password` as the `GRANT-ACCESS` user token to verify. If the token is valid then I return the JWT authentication ticket as if the user had logged in with a valid password.

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    ... code obmitted

    ApplicationUser user = await userManager.FindAsync(context.UserName, context.Password);

    if (user == null)
    {
        user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.UserName);

        ... null checks obmitted

        string token = context.Password;
        bool result = await userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user.Id, "GRANT-ACCESS", token);
    }

    ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = await user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(userManager, "JWT");

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, null);

    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```