# Return JWT Token generated by OAuthAuthorizatioServer from controller in Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, .net-4.5

Following @Taiseer Joudeh I was able to create simple POC of Web API. I'm able to create new account, then log-in and call secure Web API when I add JWT token to header.

I'd like to modify method that is responsible for creating accounts.
Right now I'm returning Create (201) code with new user object, but instead I'd like to return access token.

I've found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34526559/965722) but it requires creating `HttpClient` and doing request to OAuthAuthorizatioServer TokenEndpointPath.

[Second question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33067415/how-to-authenticate-from-web-api-controller-endpoint-when-implementing-identity) I found requires generating temporary token that is returned to front-end, but then front-end must do additional request to server to get "real" token.

What I'd like to do is to return login response (access_token, token_type and expires_in) when I create user account.
I want user to be authenticated when his account is created.

I'm using just Web API and JWT without any cookies.

**EDIT:** My temporary solution:
after creating user I'm doing this:

```
var validTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 10);
var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, "JWT");
var jwtFormat = new CustomJwtFormat(ApplicationConfiguration.Issuer);
var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { IssuedUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow, ExpiresUtc = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(validTime) };
var authenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, authenticationProperties);
var token = jwtFormat.Protect(authenticationTicket);

var response = new
{
    access_token = token,
    token_type = "bearer",
    expires_in = validTime.TotalSeconds.ToInt()
};

return Ok(response);
```

where `CustomJwtFormat` comes from [this awesome article](http://bitoftech.net/2014/10/27/json-web-token-asp-net-web-api-2-jwt-owin-authorization-server/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is some code similar to what I'm doing in my application, which is using Asp.Net Core 1.0.  Your signin and user registration will differ if you're not using Core 1.0.

```
public async Task<string> CreateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        string jwt = String.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
        {
            Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        }

        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
        if (user == null) // user doesn't exist, create user
        {
            var newUser = await _userManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationUser() { UserName = username }, password); 
            if (newUser.Succeeded) //user was successfully created, sign in user
            {
                user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
                var signInResult = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, password, false, true);
                if (signInResult.Succeeded) //user signed in, create a JWT
                {
                    var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                    List<Claim> userClaims = new List<Claim>();

                    //add any claims to the userClaims collection that you want to be part of the JWT
                    //...

                    ClaimsIdentity identity = new ClaimsIdentity(new GenericIdentity(user.UserName, "TokenAuth"), userClaims);
                    DateTime expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30); //or whatever

                    var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(
                        issuer: _tokenOptions.Issuer,  //_tokenAuthOptions is a class that holds the issuer, audience, and RSA security key
                        audience: _tokenOptions.Audience,
                        subject: identity,
                        notBefore: DateTime.Now,
                        expires: expires,
                        signingCredentials: _tokenOptions.SigningCredentials
                        );

                    jwt = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
                    Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Created;
                    await _signInManager.SignOutAsync(); //sign the user out, which deletes the cookie that gets added if you are using Identity.  It's not needed as security is based on the JWT
                }
            }
            //handle other cases...
        }
    }
```

Basically, the user is created and then signed in automatically.  I then build a JWT (add in any claims you want) and return it in the response body.  On the client side (MVC and Angular JS) I get the JWT out of the response body and store it.  It is then passed back to the server in the Authorization header of each subsequent request.  Authorization policies for all server actions are based on the set of claims supplied by the JWT.  No cookies, no state on the server.

EDIT:  I suppose you don't even need to call the signIn method in this process as you can just create the user, create a JWT, and return the JWT.  When a user logs in on a future request you would use the Sign-In, create token, Sign-Out approach.

Comment: Sorry for late reply and thank You for sharing Your code. Unfortunately I'm not using ASP.NET Core 1.0, but Your code give me an idea of using `JwtSecurityTokenHandler`. I'll try that right away!

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. I've added some code that I have in my project as a temporary solution. It works, but maybe it can be improved.

Comment: Looks good to me.  You set the properties/claims that are part of the token, create the token, return it to the user.

Answer (score 2):

The idea of sending a response with access_token, token_type and expires_in, when the user is created is a great idea. But, I would stick to calling the "/token" end point with HttpClient to achieve this task. There are quite a few security checks that needs to be performed before token is generated. Since this is security I would not take any risk. I feel comfortable using the libraries/ code provided by industry experts.

That said, I tried to come up with a class you can call to create the token once the user is created. This code has been taken from the Microsoft's implementation of OAuth Authorization Server in their Katana project. You can access the source [here](http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs). As you can see there is quite a lot happening when creating the token.

Here is the modified version of that middleware class for generating the token. You have to provide the proper OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions, Context, username, password, Scopes and clientid to get an access token. Please note that this is a sample implementation to guide you in the right direction. Please test it thoroughly if you want to use this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AspNetIdentity.WebApi.Providers;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth;

namespace WebApi.AccessToken
{
    public class TokenGenerator
    {
        public string ClientId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public IList<string> Scope { get; set; }

        private OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions Options { get; } =
            new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                //For Dev enviroment only (on production should be AllowInsecureHttp = false)
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/oauth/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                Provider = new CustomOAuthProvider(),
                AccessTokenFormat = new CustomJwtFormat("http://localhost:59822")
            };

        public async Task<IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>  InvokeTokenEndpointAsync(IOwinContext owinContext)
        {
            var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

            DateTimeOffset currentUtc = Options.SystemClock.UtcNow;
            // remove milliseconds in case they don't round-trip
            currentUtc = currentUtc.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(currentUtc.Millisecond));

            AuthenticationTicket ticket = await InvokeTokenEndpointResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrantAsync(owinContext, Options, currentUtc);

            if (ticket == null)
            {
                result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ERROR", "Failed to create acess_token"));
                return result;
            }

            ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
            ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(Options.AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan);
            ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(ticket.Identity, ticket.Properties);

            var accessTokenContext = new AuthenticationTokenCreateContext(
                owinContext,
                Options.AccessTokenFormat,
                ticket);

            await Options.AccessTokenProvider.CreateAsync(accessTokenContext);
            string accessToken = accessTokenContext.Token;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken))
            {
                accessToken = accessTokenContext.SerializeTicket();
            }

            DateTimeOffset? accessTokenExpiresUtc = ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

            result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("access_token", accessToken));
            result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("token_type", "bearer"));
            TimeSpan? expiresTimeSpan = accessTokenExpiresUtc - currentUtc;
            var expiresIn = (long)expiresTimeSpan.Value.TotalSeconds;
            if (expiresIn > 0)
            {
                result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("expires_in", "bearer"));
            }
            return result;
        }

        private async Task<AuthenticationTicket> InvokeTokenEndpointResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrantAsync(IOwinContext owinContext, OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options, DateTimeOffset currentUtc)
        {
            var grantContext = new OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext(
                owinContext, 
                options, 
                ClientId, 
                UserName, 
                Password, 
                Scope);
            await options.Provider.GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(grantContext);
            return grantContext.Ticket;
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: Thank You for sharing Your code and for link. I've noticed in my code I have custom AccessTokenFormat class that is based on `ISecureDataFormat`. It is used to generate token by `OAuthAuthorizationServer`. Maybe I could use it instead of creating new class. Could You maybe add some code showing how to use Your code?

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. I've added some code that I have in my project as a temporary solution. It works, but maybe it can be improved.

Comment: Misiu, what you doing is what actually happens in OwinAuthenticationMiddleware in asp.net for token creation. Here you are manually setting the values. The article you referenced is a great source. Use caution if you are using the built in middleware to generate the tokens for user logins (after the creation), as these two may be different. As long as the claims are same it should be okay though. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the following article: http://bitoftech.net/2015/02/16/implement-oauth-json-web-tokens-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-and-identity-2/

The general approach to authenticating a user in this case is

1. Make an HTTP call to the token endpoint
2. User Enters the credentials at the UI that is rendered
3. IdP verifies the credentials and issues a token
4. User makes another call to an authorized endpoint and OWIN will validate this (JWT) token (as configured in the ConfigureOAuthTokenConsumption method) and if successfull will set a user session with expiry same as the token expiry. The session is set using session cookies.

Now try to understand that in general, this whole process of authentication is required because your server does not trust the user logging in to be the user the person is claiming to be. However, in your case, you (or your server code) just created a user and you know for sure that the person accessing your website is the user you have just created. In this case you don't need to validate a token to create a session for this user. Just create a session with an expiry that suits your use-case.

The next time the user will have to log-in and prove him/herself to the server using a token but this time the user does not need to prove him/her self.

Note: If you absolutely are adamant about requiring a token to log in a user who you yourself have just created using their credentials here are a couple of issues.

- You are taking on the responsibility of storing (having access to) the user credentials, which might not be with you over the lifetime of the application (in most cases you might want to act as a relying party rather than an IdP).
- Even if you want to then doing it is not trivial. You will have to make the calls to the token end point in code (server or client side) on behalf of the user, enter their credentials for them, retrieve the token, call an authenticated endpoint on your site and retrieve the session cookie all while hiding all this from the user, which probably is something you will either do if you hate yourself :) but also isn't very secure way of doing things especially when you are taking all the trouble to implement OAuth in the first place.

Also, take a look at Windows Server 2016 (technical preview 5 at this time) which supports implicit grants and might take writing all this custom code off your plate if you can wait a bit for RTM.

Comment: Thank You for such detailed reply. In my case I'm not using cookies or sessions. I have WebAPI server on one machine and calls are done from website via javascript. In my case I'm validating user when he is registering (he needs invitation code to create account), then I'd like him to be able to for example fill additional fields without need to log-in. In template from visual studio (SPA application) this is done using cookies, but as I wrote I'm not using them, just JWT token. Basically I dont want user to must login just after he created his account.

Comment: I'm not setting a cookie, I didn't set any settings related to cookies. I've implemented JWT token creation and as I wrote before I'm not using MVC only WebAPI. I have no sessions. The only way I'm authenticating users is by token that is send inside header. Sorry I didn't wrote that up front.

Comment: Classic ASP to ASP.Net to MVC to Web API... all use cookies for session management. There is a cookie-less session as well (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479314.aspx) but OAuth would need custom code to work with it.

Comment: As I wrote in comment to Your second answer I not using sessions because my front-end is done in javascript. I'm not using MVC, my WebAPI endpoint is returning simple JSON data. User validation is done entirely based on JWT Tokens. All of that works, I just want to avoid that one extra request and get token in same request as account creation is.

Comment: User validation is different than session maintenance: Regardless how you do your validation (using OAuth exchanging JWT tokens) you would need to use cookies for session maintenance. And yes, cookies are needed even if it's JavaScript. JWT token is used only once for authentication not for session maintenance (or in other words keeping the user logged in.) For that the OAuth component of the OWIN pipeline sets the cookie. Hence to log in the user after you just created an account for that user you just need to create a session for that user on the server (verses authenticating him/her again).

Comment: I must disagree. When user logs in to system he must make request with valid credentials to auth endpoint, then that endpoint returns token. I can restart server, make request from other computer, even from different frontend with that token in header and I'll make valid request. So there is no session, no cookies. Token is validated each request. Inside token I have user ID, token valid date and other info I need. These were planned from beginning - no session and no cookies.

Answer (score 0):

In an OAuth solution **you as a developer** are are not required to handle the cookie setting yourself. The cookie handling is done for you automatically by the framework.

Also the only way to set a session is a. Using session cookies or b. Use cookie-less (in the url) methods. Look at http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/02/19/introducing-adal-js-v1/ for more details on token validation and session establishment (also search the term cookie and you will know what all it's used for).

If you start thinking about not using cookies at all not only will you have to figure out how to maintain session and do it securely without cookies but also have to re-write the token refresh code that detects and refreshes the token for you based on the presence of a session cookie. (i.e. not a smart idea)

Comment: I'm, not using Active Directory. I have WebAPI only solution using OWIN and Asp.Net Identity 2, I've done POC following this blog serie: http://bitoftech.net/2015/03/31/asp-net-web-api-claims-authorization-with-asp-net-identity-2-1/ After normal account creation (using WebAPI) user must do another request to token endpoint to get token, then that token is added to every request in header. Token is stored on client side in localstorage. Front end is done in Angular.There aren't any sessions or cookies. Point of my question wasn't cookies but how to return JWT token from WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the exact technology stack and recently implemented token based authorization successfully. The link I took reference from had very neatly defined the token-based auth in Web APIs. A must bookmark page I must say. Here is the link: [TOKEN BASED AUTHENTICATION IN WEB APIs](http://www.primaryobjects.com/2015/05/08/token-based-authentication-for-web-service-apis-in-c-mvc-net/).

Comment: Thanks for link, but I'm actually using ASP.NET Identity and JWT as Token format. I want to avoid reinventing the wheel, especially because of security concerns. As You wrote this is a must have bookmark, but for someone who wants to create tokens by hand.